# A very basic PHP modification I can't quite put into words for Google

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a very basic WordPress website for my dad and wanted to replace the theme's in-built need for an image logo and add a text logo.

The theme developer gave me this to add to functions.php:

```
add_filter('avf_logo_subtext', 'kriesi_logo_addition');
function kriesi_logo_addition($sub) {
    $sub .= "<h5>WEBSITE TITLE</h5>";
    return $sub;
}
function remove_title_attr(){
?>
```

Works just as expected.

However, I now want the logo to link back to the home page. I'm a complete newbie and just assumed I could put link tags within the h5 brackets, but this breaks the site. Where in the above can I put the link? The theme developer won't respond to my latest question.

Thanks in advance, and please remember we all have to start somewhere! I'm only young and this is not a paid project hence my lack of knowledge.

Comment: Have you tried putting the `<a>` tag around the `<h5>`, because you should put them around it instead of inside

Comment: how do you type the link tags?

Comment: Like the answer of Sandra, but how do you mean it breaks?

Answer (score 2):

You can link back to home page using `site_url()` function in wordpress.

```
function kriesi_logo_addition($sub) {
    $sub .= "<a href=".site_url()."><h5>WEBSITE TITLE</h5></a>";
    return $sub;
}
```